# Add aggregated columns to pivot without join

Tags: dataframe, group-by, pyspark, pivot-table

Considering the table:

```
df=sc.parallelize([(1,1,1),(5,0,2),(27,1,1),(1,0,3),(5,1,1),(1,0,2)]).toDF(['id', 'error', 'timestamp'])
df.show()

+---+-----+---------+
| id|error|timestamp|
+---+-----+---------+
|  1|    1|        1|
|  5|    0|        2|
| 27|    1|        1|
|  1|    0|        3|
|  5|    1|        1|
|  1|    0|        2|
+---+-----+---------+
```

I would like to make a pivot on `timestamp` column keeping some other aggregated information from the original table. The result I am interested in can be achieved by

```
df1=df.groupBy('id').agg(sf.sum('error').alias('Ne'),sf.count('*').alias('cnt'))
df2=df.groupBy('id').pivot('timestamp').agg(sf.count('*')).fillna(0)
df1.join(df2, on='id').filter(sf.col('cnt')>1).show()
```

with the resulting table:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id| Ne|cnt|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  5|  1|  2|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|  3|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

However, there are at least  two issues with the mentioned solution:

1. I am filtering by `cnt` at the end of the script. If I would be able to do this at the beginning, I can avoid almost all processing, because a large portion of data is removed using this filtration. Is there any way how to do this excepting `collect` and `isin` methods?
2. I am doing `groupBy` on `id` two-times. First, to aggregate some columns I need in results and the second time to get the pivot columns. Finally, I need `join` to merge these columns. I feel that I am surely missing some solution because it should be possible to do this with just one `groubBy` and without `join`, but I cannot figure out, how to do this.

Comment: you can move the filter to the first groupBy query and only filter for cnt>1 on df1. This should not change your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is indeed possible to avoid `join` using `Window` as

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy('id')
w2 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'timestamp')
df.select('id', 'timestamp', 
          sf.sum('error').over(w1).alias('Ne'), 
          sf.count('*').over(w1).alias('cnt'),
          sf.count('*').over(w2).alias('cnt_2')
         ).filter(sf.col('cnt')>1) \
  .groupBy('id', 'Ne', 'cnt').pivot('timestamp').agg(sf.first('cnt_2')).fillna(0).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not get around the join, because the pivot will need the timestamp values and the first grouping should not consider them. So if you have to create the `NE` and `cnt` values you have to group the dataframe only by `id` which results in the loss of timestamp if you want to preserve the values in columns you have to do the pivot as you did separately and join it back.

The only improvement that can be done is to move the filter to the df1 creation. So as you said this could already improve the performance since df1 should be much smaller after the filtering for your real data.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df=sc.parallelize([(1,1,1),(5,0,2),(27,1,1),(1,0,3),(5,1,1),(1,0,2)]).toDF(['id', 'error', 'timestamp'])
df1=df.groupBy('id').agg(sum('error').alias('Ne'),count('*').alias('cnt')).filter(col('cnt')>1)
df2=df.groupBy('id').pivot('timestamp').agg(count('*')).fillna(0)
df1.join(df2, on='id').show()
```

Output:

```python
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id| Ne|cnt|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  5|  1|  2|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|  3|  1|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```